# Change existing table structure

Tags: sql-server

I’ve a table ‘YearClass’ with below columns

```
Year    Class Id
2013    20
2013    30
2013    40
2014    20
2014    30
2014    40
2015    20
2015    30
```

In my application, there is a dropdown to display classes based on year selected. For any year, if the class not carried over then that row not added to ‘YearClass’ table (Like for 2015 year, class 40 not applicable so no row inserted in the table at start of that year).  **Insertions into this table take place at the start of year**. Suppose during the middle of the year, if we decided to end a class early, then table design should be changed and thinking of two ways:

a.  Add ‘Active’ column to the above table and set the column value to false when closing a class early. This involves changing existing data to set Active to false for all the prior years.

b.  Add another table ‘YearClass_Inactive’, insert a row into this table, while loading data for class drop down then eliminate the row if exists in ‘YearClass_Inactive’ table. This doesn’t require changing existing data in ‘YearClass’ table.

Which approach is good or Are there any disadvantages with each approach? Any other ways to accomplish this requirement?

Comment: Quite typical solution is to add EndDate, which is null if the class hasn't ended

Comment: yeah, enddate sounds good rather than active column since we can track when the class ended. Still the existing data must be changed to accommodate this new requirement.